# Argument passing to controller actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a controller with a postback action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult test(string x) { ... }
```

and I wanted to add a GET action with the same signature:

```
public ActionResult test(string y) { ... }
```

but the compiler pukes:

```
Type 'TestController' already defines a member called 'test' with 
the same parameter types
```

so I thought to change the signature:

```
public ActionResult test(RouteValueDictionary args) { ... }
```

and call it like this:

```
@{
    RouteValueDictionary args = new RouteValueDictionary(
        new { y = "test" }
    );
}
@Html.Action("test", "TestController", args)
```

but the controller receives `args` as null.  clearly I don't get how this is supposed to work.  I know I could just rename the action but I'd like to know how to declare it such that my dictionary comes across.

TIA - e

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can keep the signature and just change the name of the method, but use the same action name by specifying the `ActionNameAttribute`.

For example

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Foo(FooModel model)
{
   // do stuff
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Foo")]
public ActionResult FooPost(FooModel model)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

The method names are different, but the MVC action is the same for both: "Foo".

Comment: I prefer to add a `FormCollection` parameter to the post model if they're the exact same signature so that I don't have to worry about the magic strings that may change in the future :)

Comment: @BuildStarted Giving up model-binding because of that string seems a peculiar choice, in light of the fact that action names are already specified as strings all over the place: in views, redirects, routes, etc.

Comment: No no, I'm not giving it up - I just *add* the FormCollection to the parameters to make the signature different :)

Comment: @BuildStarted, that's clever (adding the FormCollection).  thanks!